# PHP login with mysql authorized error

Tags: php, html, mysql

Questions of this sort have been asked before, though i am still having issues, also is this the most current up to date syntax for PHP.

i'm not sure if im logging in correctly, it seems as though whenever i login it runs though the if(isset) as well as if(!authorized)

any help in the right direction would be very grateful.

login . php

```
        <table width="300" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
        <tr>
        <form name="form1" method="post" action="checklogin.php">
        <td>
        <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
        <tr>
        <td colspan="3"><strong>Member Login </strong></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td width="78">Username</td>
        <td width="6">:</td>
        <td width="294"><input name="myusername" type="text" id="myusername"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>Password</td>
        <td>:</td>
        <td><input name="mypassword" type="text" id="mypassword"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Login"></td>
        </tr>
        </table>
        </td>
        </form>
        </tr>
        </table>
```

checklogin . php
                                                                    // In PHP this is the way to do comments, also reopening PHP.
            DEFINE ('DB_USER', 'root');                                         // Defining database user.
            DEFINE ('DB_PSWD', '');                                             // Defining database password.
            DEFINE ('DB_HOST', 'localhost');                                    // Defining database host.
            DEFINE ('DB_NAME', 'photo');                                        // Defining database name.

```
        $tbl_name="userpass"; // Table name 
        $dbcon = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PSWD, DB_NAME);         // Connecting to mySQL with defined above.

        if (!$dbcon){                                                       // If error in connecting, mySQL error. 
            die('Could Not Connect: ' . mysql_error());                     // Give mySQL error.
        }                                                                   

        $db_selected = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $dbcon);                    // Selecting Database based on name.

        if (!$db_selected){                                                 // If error in connecting, mySQL error.
            die('Could Not Use: ' . DB_NAME . ' : ' . mysql_error());       // Give mySQL error.
        }

        // username and password sent from form
        $myusername=$_POST['myusername'];
        $mypassword=$_POST['mypassword'];

        // To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection)
        $myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
        $mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
        $myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
        $mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);

        $sql="SELECT * FROM " . $tbl_name." WHERE user='".$myusername."' and password='".$mypassword."'";
        $result=mysql_query($sql);

        // Mysql_num_row is counting table row
        $count=mysql_num_rows($result);

        // If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row

        if($count==1){
        session_start();            
        $_SESSION['$myusername'];
        $_SESSION['$mypassword'];
        header("location:loggedin.php");
     }
     else {
     session_unset();
     session_destroy();
     $_SESSION = array();
     session_start();        
     }
```

loggedin . php

```
    // Check if session is not registered, redirect back to main page.
    // Put this code in first line of web page.
    $authorized=false;
    @session_start();
    if(isset($_SESSION['myusername'],$_SESSION['mypassword']))
    {
        $authorized = true;
    }

    if(!authorized)
    {
        header('location:login.php');
        exit();
    }


        Login Successful
```

Comment: as for most current up to date.....do not use mysql_* functions, use PDO instead...http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you have it set up, what you actually want is

```
$_SESSION['myusername'] = $myusername;
$_SESSION['mypassword'] = $mypassword;
```

What you're actually doing right now is retrieving the values from the session with the keys of the literal username and password, not inserting the values into the session with the keys 'myusername' and 'mypassword'.

While we're on the subject, you don't want to be storing passwords in the session, or anywhere else for that matter. Make sure you are storing a salted and hashed value of the password. When the user provides the password, hash it on the server side and compare the resulting hash to the hash stored in the database.

Comment: Thanks for all of your help Dan, i did as you said and took out $_SESSION['mypassword'] = $mypassword; and will hash it on input.

Answer (score 0):

In checklogin.php you set the variables as follows

```
$_SESSION['$myusername'];
$_SESSION['$mypassword'];
```

and in loggedin.php you checked them as follows

```
if(isset($_SESSION['myusername'],$_SESSION['mypassword']))
```

The names are different since you use a "$" for the key of the session in checklogin.php and don't use it in loggedin.php and I don't suggest you do this
instead I suggest you set

```
$_SESSION['logged_in'] = 1;
```

and then you check that for validity in loggedin.php. Also I noticed that you're missing a "$" in your if clause in the loggedin.php file, so it should become

```
    if(!$authorized)
```